# How to install an existing Symfony project in local?

Tags: symfony, localhost, composer-php

I have a project in a web server and I am trying to run it in local

What are the procedures?

Should I download all the files (including vendor, app, bin, cache...)?

Or it is better to install by composer?

There any configuration change that I must do in special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## - if you have versioned code on bitbucket, github...

1) export your database from the web server

2) locally import database from 1)

3) checkout/clone your code from remote repository

4) composer install (enter new database credentials and other stuff)

## - if your code is not versioned

1) download your whole project

2) export your database from web server

3) locally import database from 2)

4) manually delete your cache, vendor and logs directory

5) composer install (enter new database credentials and other config stuff)

---

Start built-in Sf server by tying "php bin/console server:start" or "php app/console server:start" (Sf version < 3)

Go to http://localhost:8000 and see if your app is available

Comment: I expected to run into some issue with this, but it worked like magic.